# Parsing string to time in RubyMotion

Tags: ruby, rubymotion

I try to parse a text representation of a time into a ruby Time object.

Normally in ruby I would do it like this:

```
require 'time'
Time.parse('2010-12-15T13:16:45Z')
# => 2010-12-15 13:16:45 UTC
```

In RubyMotion I am unable to require libs and Time.parse is not available:

```
(main)> require 'time'
=> #<RuntimeError: #require is not supported in RubyMotion>
(main)>
(main)> Time.parse
=> #<NoMethodError: undefined method `parse' for Time:Class>
```

Is there a way to require the time library provided by ruby without having to copy and rewrite the whole code to make it compatible with RubyMotion?

Comment: Unable to require libs? If true you should run away from it screaming.

Comment: @pguardiario You can use 3rd party libraries by vendoring them ([see docs](http://www.rubymotion.com/developer-center/guides/project-management/#_using_3rd_party_libraries)). I could copy time.rb from ruby1.9 and remove the `require 'date'` statement. But I hope there is a better/easier way to do this.

Comment: You should have full access to iOS SDK. There are time parsing functions there.

Comment: You need to use the same APIs Objective-C uses for some things, so `NSDate` and `NSDateFormatter` will get the job done.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not as automatic, but you could use `NSDateFormatter`

```
date_formatter = NSDateFormatter.alloc.init
date_formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
date = date_formatter.dateFromString "2010-12-15T13:16:45Z"
puts date.description
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. `date` is already a Time object if you do it like this. `date.class.ancestors #=> [Time, Comparable, NSDate, NSObject, Kernel]`

Answer (score 11):

While Paul.s answer certainly works, it was giving me the creeps, looking at it in my code, so I kept looking.

Matt Aimonetti's MacRuby book has some good stuff:

http://books.google.ca/books?id=WPhdPzyU1R4C&pg=PA43&lpg=PA43&dq=macruby+nsdate&source=bl&ots=j7Y3J-oBcV&sig=FTr0KyKae-FinH-HNEWBcAAma1s&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ANT0T7mkEM6jqwHx7LjeAw&ved=0CGEQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=macruby%20nsdate&f=false

Where parsing is as simple as:

```
NSDate.dateWithString(<your date string here>)
```

or

```
NSDate.dateWithNaturalLanguageString(<all kinds of date strings>)
```

And if you absolutely have to have a Time object from that:

```
Time.at(NSDate.date)
```

Comment: Thanks for your additional input.

Comment: I don't think NSDate.dateWithString is available on iOS. Thought I'd flag that since the question was regarding Rubymotion dates and not MacRuby.

Comment: I know it's been a long time, but I thought I'd address Dave's caveat.  This works just fine in RubyMotion.

Comment: You are my hero. dateFromString was throwing me nil in an iPhone 4S with iOS 7.1.1. But it worked fine in an iPad 2 and simulators. I changed all that with NSDate.dateWithNaturalLanguageString(string), like you suggested. Worked like a beast! BTW I'm using RubyMotion 2.28. Thanks. (The issue may happen in an iPhone 5 as well, according to this post: http://www.copyquery.com/hardware-dependent-nsdateformatter-datefromstring-bug-returns-nil/)

Answer (score 2):

[BubbleWrap](http://bubblewrap.io/) adds some nice wrappers around this:

> Time
>
> The Time Ruby class was added a class level method to convert a
>   iso8601 formatted string into a Time instance.
>
> Time.iso8601("2012-05-31T19:41:33Z")
>   => 2012-05-31 21:41:33 +0200

This will give you a NSDate instance, simple as that.

Comment: Time → Comparable → NSDate → NSObject → Kernel

Comment: Better use Ruby Time class. Reference:[http://www.rubymotion.com/developer-center/guides/runtime/#_builtin_classes](http://www.rubymotion.com/developer-center/guides/runtime/#_builtin_classes)

Comment: How can I loose the +0200 at the end?

Comment: Check strftime in the ruby docs http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime for defining custom time formats.

Comment: For instance `Time.iso8601("2012-05-31T19:41:33Z").strftime('%m/%d/%Y')`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this has since been fixed. I'm parsing times in RubyMotion no problem.

```
(main)> Time.parse("2016-01-21 10:33:07")
=> "2016-01-21 10:33:07 -0800"
```

RubyMotion 4.8

```
$ motion --version
4.8
```

Comment: You must be using the `motion-support` gem.