# Is there a way to get time ago in words in rubymotion

Tags: ruby, rubymotion

Is there a way to get time ago in words in rubymotion such that when I have a date I can get the `2 days ago` `5 days ago` etc. from the current date? like its possible to do in rails.

The date format I am getting from mysql database is TIMESTAMP and the returned data is like this:

```
2014-05-17 22:59:07
2011-05-17 22:56:02
```

**Question**

How can I convert the above string to NSDate and then compare it to today's date and get "X days ago" etc...

Comment: that doesn't work in RubyMotion

Comment: You could just implement something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/195894/557015

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BubbleWrap](https://github.com/rubymotion/BubbleWrap) to convert your timestamp into a NSDate instance.

> The Time Ruby class was added a class level method to convert a
>   iso8601 formatted string into a Time instance.

```
Time.iso8601("2012-05-31T19:41:33Z")
=> 2012-05-31 21:41:33 +0200
```

Then you can do as you wish with it, [sugar cube](https://github.com/rubymotion/sugarcube/wiki/NSDate#nsdate-additions) has some nice extensions for NSDate.

More answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718099/parsing-string-to-time-in-rubymotion)...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a CocoaPod that can handle that: https://github.com/MatthewYork/DateTools

Add `pod 'DateTools'` to your Rakefile. Run `rake pod:install` and now you can convert your date objects like this:

```
my_date = NSDate.dateWithNaturalLanguageString('2015-08-18T23:58:40.000+00:00')
my_date.timeAgoSinceNow
```